# How do I get this colorpicker to show in a modal without a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal w/ a colorpicker. When I select to change the color, you can't see the full pallette unless you scroll down.

As a test, I put a jqueryui datepicker in the modal and the full datepicker shows when you click it. How do I get the same functionality w/ the colorpicker? I tried changing the z-index of the colorpicker, but that didn't seem to do anything.

(Note: I don't want [this](http://www.revillwebdesign.com/change-the-height-width-and-position-of-a-modal-in-twitter-bootstrap/), where the height of the modal changes)

Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7hAY/) and code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="http://evoluteur.github.com/colorpicker/css/evol.colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="http://evoluteur.github.com/colorpicker/js/evol.colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color_picker").colorpicker();
});


$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>


<body>

    <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
    <input id="color_picker" value="#92cddc"/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `overflow-y` property of the modal body do visible:

```
#myModal .modal-body {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

**Edit:**

If your content doesn't fit the dialog, you will have to change the `height` or `max-height` properties to fit.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an event on click to the input that opens the color selector like this

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $('#color_picker').click(function (){
        $('.modal-body').animate({minHeight: '300px'});        
    });
});
```

and then on click on the color box or something animate height back to its original quantity
hope it helped, bye.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround bandage solution only.  You can modify the following functions in evol.colorpicker.js source code. Perhaps, you can try converting it a prototype or extend function without changing the source code.

```
 _create: function() {
            ..............................
             // change the following code to pass the evt to show palette
    if(showOn==='both' || showOn==='button'){
                e.next().on('click', function(evt){
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    that.showPalette(evt);
                });
            }
                     }               
             }
              ....................


  showPalette: function (e) {       
    if(this._enabled){
        this._active=true;
        $('.colorPicker').not('.'+this._id).colorpicker('hidePalette');
        if(this._palette===null){
            this._palette = $('#YOUR_DIALOG_DIV_ID')                                        
                .after(this._paletteHTML()).next()
                .css({ top: e.clientY + 'px', left: e.clientX + 'px', position: 'absolute' })
                .on('click',function(evt){
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                });
            this._bindColors();
            var that=this;
            if(this._isPopup){
                $(document.body).on('click.'+that._id, function(evt){
                    if(evt.target!=that.element.get(0)){
                        that.hidePalette();
                    }
                }).on('keyup.'+that._id, function(evt){
                    if(evt.keyCode===27){
                        that.hidePalette();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
},
```