# How do I get this colorpicker to show in a boostrap accordion (without changing the height of the accordion)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[I asked a similar question regarding colorpickers and modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914986/how-do-i-get-this-colorpicker-to-show-in-a-modal-without-a-scrollbar) but now I am having the same issue with a colorpicker and a bootstrap accordion. [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7hAY/20/). I tried 'overflow-y: visible;' on pretty much anything I thought would work, but unfortunately it doesn't. Again, I don't want to change the height of the accordion, just be able to view the colorpicker.

```
.accordion{
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.accordion-group{
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.accordion-heading{
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.accordion-inner{
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you must overwrite bootstrap collapse class overflow property.

```
.accordion-group .collapse{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7hAY/21/)